# Android : Volley call cancels on screen timeout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-volley

I am developing Android app using Volley library for network calls.
While http get call in progress if screen timeouts, API call gets rejected.

Please provide some info related to this if anybody facing the same problem.

Here is my code :

```
CustomStringRequest customStringRequest = new CustomStringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (jsonObject.getBoolean(JSONHelper.TAG_SUCCESS)) {
                                iNetworkOperationHandler.onResponseSucceed(
                                        jsonObject, requestId, extraInfo);

                            } else if (!jsonObject
                                    .getBoolean(JSONHelper.TAG_SUCCESS)) {
                                iNetworkOperationHandler.onResponseFailed(
                                        response, requestId, extraInfo);

                            } else {
                                iNetworkOperationHandler.onResponseError(
                                        response, requestId, extraInfo);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                            iNetworkOperationHandler.onJSONException(e,
                                    requestId, extraInfo);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        iNetworkOperationHandler.onErrorReceived(error,
                                requestId, extraInfo);

                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                if (null != headers) {
                    return headers;
                } else {
                    return UrlClass.getHeader();
                }

            }

        };
        customStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                ApplicationBaseLimits.TIMEOUT_NORMAL_MILLISECONDS, 0, 1f));
        customStringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        appCntrlr.addToRequestQueue(customStringRequest, TAG);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)); set this on your request, which doubles default timeout seconds

Comment: Got it. My mistake. Calling cancelAll(TAG) inside onStop(). So all calls are getting removed.